# black stain on my glass stove top

Tags: cleaning

i have a black stain on one of my stove tops there were some smaller ones on the other three but they came off fairly easy. this has taken up almost the entire top and looks almost as if the pattern was peeled off leaving a black bottom but you cannot see the burner when it is on. Is there a way I can remove this stain?

[image]

Comment: that's a very tiny low quality image. What kind of stove top is that? What caused the stain? please [edit] your question to add more information

Comment: I can't be 100% sure from the picture -- but oil will turn black when it gets hot enough ... so if some gets underneath the pan, you can end up with stains like that.  I've seen it happen on a black glass top stove, where it was only slightly raised and no longer shiny ... and I can't remember what I did to clean it ... might've been barkeeper's friend, or just a lot of scrubbing w/ a scotchbrite pad or similar.

Answer (score 1):

Try oven cleaner spray, let it sit for 30min. Wipe off and clean with water. A razor blade scrape might also be tried if its charcoal burnt in.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Barkeeper’s Friend](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01NCV9OBG). Use the powder, a minimally-abrasive sponge that is barely wet, and scrub away. It's a 5 minute job.

Comment: You are writing on an international forum. Can you add a link to the product so that people can check what this is?

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Bar-Keepers-Friend-Powdered-21-Ounces/dp/B01NCV9OBG/ref=sr_1_3?crid=28VH9TY5JBW9O&keywords=barkeeper%27s%2Bfriend&qid=1564156351&s=gateway&sprefix=barkeepe%2Caps%2C180&sr=8-3&th=1